# What controls the cleanup of the /tmp/systemd-private* directories?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos7, httpd, systemd

It doesn't seem like the systemd-tmpfiles service cleans up these folders because I have files in `/tmp/systemd-private-*-httpd.service-*/tmp/` that are 27ish days old (the last time httpd was restarted).  If I'm reading the `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` file correctly then the inner tmp dir should be getting cleaned out every 10 days because of `v /tmp 1777 root root 10d` and `X /tmp/systemd-private-%b-*/tmp` right?  I believe I read in the man that `X` is don't delete the dir but delete everything inside of it.
My systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer service is set to `OnBootSec=15min` and `OnUnitActiveSec=1d`

So am I understanding this correctly, or is there another service that's in charge of cleaning that dir, or..  is something just broken?  TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is broken.

systemd should not disturb a temporary directory *that is still in use* by a service, as yours is. Once it is no longer in use, then it is eligible to be cleaned up.

The x/X means to ignore the directory, according to the man page:

```
     #Type Path                                     Mode User Group Age          Argument
     x     /path-or-glob/to/ignore                  -    -    -     -            -
     X     /path-or-glob/to/ignore/recursively      -    -    -     -            -
```

When the service stops, systemd will delete the entire systemd-private temporary directory at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  That was my initial understanding of the X type, but further down the man there's this line in the explanation `Unlike x, this parameter will not exclude the content if path is a directory, but only directory itself.` which seems to say that since /tmp/sysd.../tmp is a dir that it's contents would not be excluded.

Comment: @Exlipse That's a good point. I'm not sure if the man page is wrong there or I am. I'll dig into a bit further.